# cmd if script won't work

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
pause
color 0a
mode 1000

set /p apps = where do you want to go to?
echo metrix = 1
echo nothing = 2
pause

if %apps% == 1 goto metrix
if %apps% == 2 goto nothing

:metrix
:start
echo %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random% %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random% %random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%%random%
goto start

:nothing
echo nothing
pause
exit
```

why doesnt it woerk?

I copied it from a tutorial and I have no idea why doesnt it work.

Comment: *"doesn't work*" is not a valid error message. You need to be much more detailed explaining what you expect and what you get.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space before and after "=", in following statement.

set /p apps = where do you want to go to?

Answer (score 0):

Besides CuriousMind's suggestion you should also do the comparison this way:

```
if "%apps%"=="1" goto metrix
if "%apps%"=="2" goto nothing
```

Using quotes and removing redundant spaces is safer. You probably also want to write

```
echo metrix = 1
echo nothing = 2
set /p apps = where do you want to go to?
```

so that the echos are displayed before the question.